# How to split names with numbers from one common file into separate files by numbers (Names with identical numbers in one file and others in another)

Tags: python, list, file

```
student = ['Ted 904', 'John 904', 'Dan 905', 'Peter 905', 'Michael 906']
with open('a.txt', "w") as myfile:
        for c in student:
                myfile.write("%s\n" % c)
```

I have a list of students with their numbers and I have written it in file and now I need to separate them on different txt files by their similar number.

Comment: Just to be sure of the answer, the students who have scored 905 would be in one file,  904 in other and 906 in other?

Comment: @AbhasMehrotra Yes, they should be in different files

Answer (score 1):

Filenames can be created by the numbers of the students and you can do this

```
student = ['Ted 904', 'John 904', 'Dan 905', 'Peter 905', 'Michael 906']
for c in student:
    fileName= c[-3:]
    with open(fileName+'.txt', "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write("%s\n" % c)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Marks are in 3 digits always then one can do this:-

```
for i in student:
    f = i[-3:] #accessing the last 3 letters/digits of the string for filename
    with open("%s.txt" % f, "w") as myfile:
        myfile.write(c)
```

However, if you want to display Marks and Name clearly you may want to try this:

```
student = ['Ted 904', 'John 904', 'Dan 905', 'Peter 905', 'Michael 906']
df = pd.DataFrame(student, columns=['String'])
df = df['String'].str.split(" ", n = 1, expand = True)
df.columns = ['Name', 'Marks']
for m in df['Marks']:
    y = df.loc[df['Marks'] == m]
    f = open("%s.txt" % m, "w")
    f.write(str(y))
```